# How do I save a rigged character as a single asset?

Tags: asset-browser

I have a Rigify character, I tried putting the rig and all its objects it in a collection but I can't see an option to add a collection as an asset. Selecting the rig and objects puts all the pieces as different assets. If they are individual I can't find a way to place them all to the cursor... yet.

Is there a way to bring a character from the asset browser to the 3D view in one piece and vice versa?

Comment: At the moment, no.  The current [Asset Browser](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Asset_Browser) is limited to Objects, Materials, Poses and Worlds individually.  Collections will eventually be added, but until then there's no way to identify groups of objects that make a single asset.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with not being able to make an asset out of a collection.

My approach:

1. Create one vertex group within each object before rigging
2. Merge all objects into one via `cmd j`, the single parts are still accessable through the vertex groups
3. Create your armature and make sure that each bone is exactly named like the corresponding vertex group it controls
4. Select the object, then the armature and parent it (`cmd p` > `with empty groups`)
5. The bones should now automatically be asigned to the respective vertex group/part. You can check this in `Pose mode` (`cmd tab`)
6. Now right click the object (not the armature!) in the outliner and choose `mark as asset`
7. Save the file in your asset file path and the object including the parent armature should show up in the asset manager

Comment: I use Rigify that uses around a 100 bones if not more, That solution would take a sevral days just to impliment assigning every single bone a vertex group. Also, how will that affect the automatic weights when you do a Ctrl+p?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow understood "rigified" character as I don't know the Rigify addon.
I guess there is no possibility at the moment except appending a collection containing the rigged object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having the same problem in Blender 3.2.2 where collections can now be added. The problem now is that it appends the collection as an instance instead of parts connected to an armature. I can 'make instances real' and end up with an armature and a load of unconnected parts, which defeats the purpose. Back to using linked libraries I guess till this works in a useable way for anything other than simple objects in a single mesh.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/159110)